# Docker: Get service specific logs deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, dockerfile

So I have dockerized a service "**myxxx-service**" along with Tomcat.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8  

EXPOSE 8080

COPY ./myxxx-service/target/myxxx-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

cmd mkdir -p /opt/myxxx/db

copy ./myxxx-service/src/test/resources/* /opt/myxxx/db/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

When I run the docker image, I am able to get the catalina.out logs. The tomcat becomes up. I am able to open the standard tomcat page on 8080 port.

But my service shows 404 error reponse.

I want to check my service specific logs that generally comes in the **logs/myxxx-service.logs** file.

Is there a way to do that?

Note: I have tried `docker service logs`. I am not sure if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the output of your log? Is it file? 
You can always get into the instance by:

```
docker exec -it <container-id/container-name> sh
```

And then you can navigate to your logs. If you use vendors like AWS then, in your container settings, you can use `aws-log` driver and send your logs to `CloudWatch`.

Comment: Thanks.. I can navigate to the tomcat logs. Is it possible to do so by `docker-machine ssh'? Because this is where docker is running right?

Comment: The command you just used is kind of "ssh-ing" into docker container from your "docker-machine".